# jquery length of characters in a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to get the length of characters in a jQuery collection?

e.g. you matched a bunch of divs and you want the character count of just the matched divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes... you can do it this way,

```
var count = 0;
$( "selector" ).each(function(){
    count += $(this).text().length;
});

alert( count );
```

see here
http://jsfiddle.net/yTXXk/

Comment: Thanks! This fork ended up being exactly what I needed: http://jsfiddle.net/rF9T4/ Sorry about the subject matter :|